# Styled components conditional for list content with counter

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to style an ordered list with styled components in React.

I've got the following code

```
const Sublist = styled.ol`
   counter-reset: secondItem;
   margin: 10px 0 0 25px;

   li:before {
       content: ${props => props.isDeg ? counter(secondItem) `° ` : `§ ` counter(secondItem)};
       counter-increment: secondItem;
   }
`
```

I'm getting an error message for at the second counter `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}"`

How can I wrap both conditions in a way that counter will be recognized?

Comment: lose the back ticks in the condition and put one after the last accolade `}`

Comment: @Mouser Without the back ticks in the condition I'm getting the following error Unexpected character '°'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points here:

- `counter` is a css function, you cannot use it in the js function
- `content` value must be within quotes

Therefore change the line

```
content: ${props => props.isDeg ? counter(secondItem) `° ` : `§ ` counter(secondItem)};
```

to

```
content: '${props => !props.isDeg && "§ "}' counter(secondItem) '${props => props.isDeg && "° "}';
```

Answer (score 1):

counter(secondItem) is a function call which returns a value and then you need to add up the `°` with it? Then you might wanna try

```
var counter = (secondItem) => {
   return secondItem === 1 ? 'abc' : 'edf';
}
var backtickData = `${1 === 1 ? `${counter(1)} ° ` : `§ ${counter(1)}`}`;
console.log(backtickData)




const Sublist = styled.ol`
   counter-reset: secondItem;
   margin: 10px 0 0 25px;

   li:before {
       content: ${props => props.isDeg ? `${counter(secondItem)}° ` : `§ ${counter(secondItem)}`};
       counter-increment: secondItem;
   }
`
```

Let me know if this works for you :)

Comment: Doesn't work because counter and secondItem is undefined. I guess it's because counter is a css function and secondItem a css variable and the back tick notation is for js functions

Comment: Can you add your counter function? Also what is `secondItem`?

Comment: `counter` is a css function like `calc`. [https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_counters.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_counters.asp)

Comment: Damn  that's new to me